# Watchkit Extension Test Class - Bad Access Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, watchkit

I set up a test target for my Watchkit extension by following the steps mentioned in the '*How can I unit test my WatchKit extension?*' section in this [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/94672/watchkit-faq).

Then I imported a controller class from the Extension into my test class and tried to create an object for it. This is throwing a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

Import statement:
**#import "NotificationController.h"**

Creating an object:
**NotificationController *controller = [[NotificationController alloc] init];**

The controller class i imported is a sub class of **WKUserNotificationInterfaceController**. Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This post from Pivotal Labs says they hit a similar issue. http://pivotallabs.com/watchkit-test-tools-pivotalcorekit/

It sounds like using WatchKit classes directly (as you are, even with a subclass) doesn't work. Perhaps try breaking your code out into a separate, testable class and including that in your `WKInterfaceController` classes.